# pandas.DataFrame - get the UID of each row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After using `yfinance.download()`, I result in a `pandas.DataFrame` object, that, when printed, outputs to this:

```
Date                                                                                    
2018-01-02  18700.199219  18700.199219  18700.199219  18700.199219  18700.199219       0
2018-01-03  18953.099609  18953.099609  18953.099609  18953.099609  18953.099609       0
2018-01-04  18922.500000  18922.500000  18922.500000  18922.500000  18922.500000       0
2018-01-05  18849.800781  18849.800781  18849.800781  18849.800781  18849.800781       0
2018-01-08  18911.900391  18911.900391  18911.900391  18911.900391  18911.900391       0
...                  ...           ...           ...           ...           ...     ...
2022-03-04  23165.710938  23165.710938  23165.710938  23165.710938  23165.710938       0
2022-03-07  23148.070312  23148.070312  23148.070312  23148.070312  23148.070312       0
2022-03-08  23026.910156  23026.910156  23026.910156  23026.910156  23026.910156       0
2022-03-09  22659.669922  22659.669922  22659.669922  22659.669922  22659.669922       0
2022-03-10  22437.609375  22437.609375  22437.609375  22437.609375  22437.609375       0

[1061 rows x 6 columns]
```

I called it the UID since it is a unique identifier (I.e. special for each row) and it does not get classified as an column.

**How do I access the data from the "Date" column?**

Comment: what is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: Index(['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], dtype='object')

Comment: @JamesAshwood , ouput as given in the question is strnge. where are the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How do I access the data from the "Date" column?*

Reset the index first, and convert the index to a regular column:

```py
df.reset_index()['Date']
```

OR, keep `Date` column as your index and simply get the index column:

```py
df.index
```

Comment: `df.index` would also work

Comment: @JamesAshwood take sometime to think about Paul H answer. Are you sure  that having `Date` as the index does not make more sense?

Comment: It does, @PaulH, how would that work.